# How can I repeat functions for different columns after they're grouped in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking for an efficient way to product outputs for multiple columns in my data and have the outputs be in a table.

Columns in Data: GROUP, x, n, l, A, B, C, D, E, F, G

Currently my code looks like this:

```
stat.test_A <- data %>%
   t_test(A ~ GROUP, detailed = TRUE, var.equal = TRUE) %>%
    add_significance()
stat.test_A

data %>% cohens_d(A ~ GROUP var.equal = TRUE)

stat.test_B <- data %>%
   t_test(B ~ GROUP, detailed = TRUE, var.equal = TRUE) %>%
    add_significance()
stat.test_B

data %>% cohens_d(B ~ GROUP var.equal = TRUE)
```

I'd like to repeat it for columns A:G and then have the output in one table big table.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to create a function to do this

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(dat, col_nm) {
    stat_out1 <- dat %>%
       t_test(formula = 
       eval(rlang::expr(!! rlang::ensym(col_nm) ~ GROUP)),
         var.equal = TRUE, detailed = TRUE) %>%
        add_significance()
    stat_out2 <- dat %>%
     cohens_d(rlang::expr(!! rlang::ensym(col_nm) ~ GROUP)), var.equal = TRUE)
  return(dplyr::lst(stat_out1, stat_out2))

   }
```

Then, we either call it individually

```
f1(data, A)
f1(data, "A")
```

Or use a loop

```
library(purrr)
map(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), ~ f1(data, .x))
```